# How to print a module name in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you print a module name in Python?

I tried to import a module and print it, then it gives me `<module 'time' (built-in)>`.

```
import time
print(time)  # <module 'time' (built-in)>
```

How to print just the module name?

Comment: Quick tip, you can check what members a variable has with `dir(x)`, e.g. `dir(time)`. In this case you would see that is has a `__name__` attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of a module as a string is available as its `__name__` attribute.

```
>>> import time
>>> print(time.__name__)
time
```

This is shown in the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), by the way.

Answer (score -2):

Simply import a module and print its name using _name

Comment: umm sorry it gives me an error time has no attribute name

Comment: import random as a 
print(a.__name__)

Does this works for you?

Comment: yes ofc :D this answer is already answered in the upper one